# Splunk rex query to filter message

Tags: splunk, rex

I have a splunk log in the below format:

```
{"Apple":
    {"message":"abcdefgh.ijkl","code":"200"}
}
```

I want to filter the message "abcdefgh.ijkl" and code separately.

Comment: So, what have You tried so far?

Comment: rex field = message_text "{(\w+)*:(\w+)*:(?<message>(.*)\s)"

Comment: Would You be so kind and update Your question in reproducible and verifiable manner. Just like [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) describes.

Comment: in the log that I said in question will come as message_text: {}

Comment: this is how i get the log. message_text: {"data":
    {"message":"I'm a Developer.Lives in Hyderabad","code":"200"}
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this `rex` command in your query.

```
... | rex "message\":\"(?<message>[^\"]+)\",\"code\":\"(?<code>\d+)" | ...
```